# Piecewise function output response interpretation

Tags: functions, function-construction

```
Piecewise[{{t^2, t <= 0}, {t, t >= 0}}]
```

Outputs:

```
t^2   t <= 0
t     t >= 0
0     True
```

What does the last line of output 0 True mean? 
Sometimes it also outputs Indeterminate etc. Can someone describe the behavior, constraints, and limitations of this function?

Comment: see [Piecewise >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html): (1) _The Subscript[cond, i] are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield `True`. _ (2) _If all preceding Subscript[cond, i] yield `False`, then the Subscript[val, i] corresponding to the __first__ Subscript[cond, i] that yields `True` is returned as the value of the piecewise function._

Comment: ..  (3) _Piecewise[{{Subscript[val, 1],Subscript[cond, 1]}, ... },val]
uses default value __val__  if none of the Subscript[cond, i] apply. The default for val is 0._  and (4) _Piecewise[{{Subscript[val, 1],Subscript[cond, 1]},{Subscript[val, 2],Subscript[cond, 2]},...s]}]_ (i.e, single-argument form with no default value is supplied)  uses `0` as the default default-value.

Comment: The function returns `0` if neither `t >= 0` nor `t <= 0`. For example, if you define `strange /: strange >= 0 = False; strange /: strange <= 0 = False` you get a strange value which is neither `>=0` nor `<= 0`. Consequently, if you evaluate your piecewise function with `t=strange`, you'll get `0` as result.